# Create a bootable program/iso

Tags: linux, boot, usb, iso-image

I want to program my own bootable USB Stick, that means creating an iso which I can "burn" to my USB stick via unetinboot. I know there are many lightweight linux distros out there, but I just need to mount the HDD and do some basic file operations. Copy, replace and such. And I want to display something on the computer's screen.

Which programming language is used to create such a "program"? Are there libraries which I can use? Any other ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Grab a copy of a lightweight linux distro and modify it to fit your needs. If you want to start from scratch (*not recommended*), take a look at C(++) and Assembler.

Comment: Why do you want to reinvent the wheel?  There are plenty of live discs and live disc creators (OpenSuse Studio, for example) - why do you need to program anything for that?  Those allow you to just put in the functionality you need and nothing else.  ArchLinux is super light and console only for their live cd.

Answer (score 1):

To `just [...] mount the HDD and do some basic file operations` you still need to be able to operate all the hardware on the machine. So you need an OS to some extent. You could certainly strip down what that OS contains to a great extent but that's on the order of doing what the `lightweight linux distros` have already done for you. You are almost certainly best off just using one of them.

Comment: The reason I asked, is it should do the file operations automatically and fast, I don't need the other stuff.

Comment: Then find one of the custom spin tools (like @nerdwaller mentioned in his comment above) that lets you specify jobs to run upon image boot.